# ANTLR4 : mismatched input

Tags: antlr4

I would like to match the input of the form ::

```
commit a1b2c3
Author: Michael <michael@test.com>

commit d3g4
Author: David <david@test.com>
```

Here is the grammar I have written:

```
grammar commit;

file : commitinfo+;

commitinfo : commitdesc authordesc;
commitdesc : 'commit' COMMITHASH NEWLINE;
authordesc : 'Author:' AUTHORNAME '<' EMAIL '>' NEWLINE;

COMMITHASH : [a-z0-9]+;
AUTHORNAME : [a-zA-Z]+;
EMAIL      : [a-zA-Z0-9.@]+;
NEWLINE    : '\r'?'\n';
WHITESPACE : [ \t]->skip;
```

The problem with the above parser is that, for the above input it matches perfectly. But when the input changes to :

```
commit c1d2
Author: michael <michael@test.com>
```

it throws an error like :

line 2:8 mismatched input 'michael' expecting AUTHORNAME.

When I print the tokens, it seems the string 'michael' gets matched by the token COMMITHASH instead of AUTHORNAME.

How to fix the above case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ANTLR4** matches the lexer rules according to the sequence in which they have been written.

`'michael'` gets matched by the rule `COMMITHASH : [a-z0-9]+ ;` which appears before the rule `AUTHORNAME` and hence you are having the error.

I can think of the following options to resolve the issue you are facing :

- You can use the `'mode'` feature in ANTLR : In ANTLR 4, one lexer mode is active at a time, and the longest `non-fragment lexer rule` in that mode rule will determine which token is created. Your grammar only includes the default mode, so all the lexer rules are active and hence 'michael' gets matched to `COMMITHASH` as the length of the token matched is same for `COMMITHASH` and `AUTHORNAME` but `COMMITHASH` appears before `AUTHORNAME` in the grammar.
- You can alter your lexical rules by interchanging the way in which they appear in the grammar. Assuming your `COMMITHASH` rule always has a numeral matched with it. Put `AUTHORNAME` before `COMMITHASH` in the following way :

  ```
  grammar commit;
  ...

  AUTHORNAME : [a-zA-Z]+;
  COMMITHASH : [a-z0-9]+;
  ...
  ```

---

Note: I strongly feel that your lexer rules are not crisply written. Are you sure that your `COMMITHASH` rule should be `[a-z0-9]+;` This would mean a token like `'abhdks'` will also get matched by your `COMMITHASH` rule. But that's a different issue altogether.